# reading from texture2d resource in directx11

Tags: textures, directx, gpu, data, gpgpu

Hi^^ i am trying to read data in resource, which i used to do well without any problems. but suddenly it is not working.

1. first i made **immutable resource** that has data in it, which is 
   `XMFLOAT4(1,1,1,1)` here.
2. next i made **staging resource** for reading.
3. lastly, i called map/unmap to read and store data into `outputArr`.

```
//(all HRESULT checked already)
    int WIDTH = 10, HEIGHT = 2;

    ID3D11Texture2D* resource; // create texture------------------------------
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    texDesc.Width = WIDTH;
    texDesc.Height = HEIGHT;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    XMFLOAT4* initValues = new XMFLOAT4[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; ++i) {
        initValues[i] = XMFLOAT4(1,1,1,1);
    }
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    data.pSysMem = initValues;
    data.SysMemPitch = sizeof(XMFLOAT4)*WIDTH;
    data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    device->CreateTexture2D(
        &texDesc,
        &data,
        &resource);

    ID3D11Texture2D* staging; // create texture for reading --------------------
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC stgDesc;
    stgDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    stgDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    stgDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    stgDesc.Width = WIDTH;
    stgDesc.Height = HEIGHT;
    stgDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    stgDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    stgDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    stgDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    stgDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    stgDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    device->CreateTexture2D(
        &stgDesc,
        nullptr,
        &staging);

    XMFLOAT4* outputArr = new XMFLOAT4[WIDTH*HEIGHT]; // READ-------------------
    dContext->CopyResource(staging, resource);
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));
    dContext->Map(staging, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedResource);

    outputArr = reinterpret_cast<XMFLOAT4*>(mappedResource.pData);
    std::vector<XMFLOAT4> testV;
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            int idx = y * WIDTH + x;

            testV.push_back(outputArr[idx]);
        }
    }

    dContext->Unmap(staging, 0);
```

and it turns out, only when `WIDTH` is multiple of 16(`HEIGHT` doesn't seem to be matter here), it copies the data well into ALL element of array, otherwise it fill out just 0 into array until next 16 element.

For example, if width/height is 10/2, 
first 10 elements of `outputArr` will have proper data and next 6 elements have just 0, and next another 10 elements with data, and 6 elements with 0, so on.

i haven't had any problem on dealing with resources. and struggle still.
just my humble assumption is that there might be specific alignment in number of width of resource that i miss. Or silly mistake in my process.

Hope anyone can find something from this question.
thanks

Comment: You need to check all functions that return ``HRESULT`` with the ``SUCCEEDED`` or ``FAILED`` macros. ``Map`` returns an ``HRESULT``.  You should also have the [Direct3D Debug Layer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers) enabled which will give you additional information.

Comment: Oops thanks. i forgot that i should mention that i checked it already. just removed that to make easier to read my code. i put the comment in first line of code now;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution. it looks even so pretty.

`testV.push_back(outputArr[idx])` 
should have been edited like

`testV.push_back(((XMFLOAT4*)((char*)mappedResource.pData + (y* mappedResource.RowPitch) + (x*sizeof(XMFLOAT4))))->y)`

i thought at first time that when i make a 2dTexture(xmfloat4) with `WIDTH * HEIGHT`, its size will be `16*WIDTH*HEIGHT`. But it was wrong !!!.
it has some automatic padding in it. so the actual size would be `(16*WIDTH + padding)*HEIGHT`. *i have no idea why, just guessing because a texture can cover a lot of different type, so it makes different padding for types automatically??? maybe*

if anyone know why, plz let me know.

thanks